# IPython up/down arrows don't scroll through history

Tags: 20.04, python3, ipython

`IPython 8.5.0.` doesn't properly scroll my history when using `up/down arrow` keys. Yet, the `%history` command still gives me the proper history. Furthermore, "search previous command history" also still works. I have had these issues ever since I upgraded IPython from `7.15.0.` to `8.5.0.`.

Example:

```py
In [1]: x = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [2]: y = 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [3]: %history                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
x = 1
y = 2
%history
```

If I now press the `up-arrow` (or `CTRL+P`), IPython cycles through some old code (seemingly random at each restart of IPython). However typing `x` and `up-arrow` will result in the historical `x = 1` statement. I want the `up-arrow` without typing anything to give me the last used statement.

`up-arrow` used to work for me in version `7.15.0.`, but now the issue persists for versions `8.2.0.` until `8.5.0.`. Is this just a change for the newer IPython versions?

All versions were installed on `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS` with `pip 22.2.2`.
I installed readline version `6.2.4.1` .

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Could this be related to the `LXterminal` as in here https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10984 ?

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue in `prompt-toolkit`; IPython 8.7.0 and above [pin to a newer version](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/13834) that fixes this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).